# aws ssh server connect port 22: operation timed out

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

I am working on the [Deploying Django to AWS ECS with Terraform | TestDriven.io](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-ecs-with-terraform/#nginx) tutorial and while I was following the steps, I tried to connect all of my instances via ssh by following [New: Using Amazon EC2 Instance Connect for SSH access to your EC2 Instances | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/).

By following the section where it starts by "connecting to an instance using EC2 Instance Connect", I typed in:

```
$ aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --region us-east-1 --instance-id i-0989ec3292613a4f9 --availability-zone us-east-1f --instance-os-user ec2-user --ssh-public-key file://mynew_key.pub
```

command on the terminal to push the public key to the instance using the `send-ssh-public-key`.

After that, I tried to connect to the instance using the associated private key:

```
$ ssh -I mynew_key ec2-user@ec2-34-204-200-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

It successfully worked out and I came to the end of the deploying Django tutorial. But when I was testing whether it properly connects to the server using the `http://(load balancer IP)` template, I kept getting a `503 service unavailable` error.

So, I fixed the issue by changing the inbound rule sources to `0.0.0.0/0`, but after that, it still gave me a `502 Bad Gateway` error. To find where the issue was happening, I checked whether the instances were connected properly and it gave me an error saying:

> ssh: connect to host xx port 22: Operation timed out

To resolve this, I found [ssh operation timed out | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU5iD0Y2PZQF2arom2BAojuA/ssh-operation-timed-out). So everything else passed except the last solution, which was to Ping the IP address. When I Ping the IP address, it gave me a `Request timed out` error and I am very lost on how to fix this issue (my computer is Mac OS!).

It will be great if someone could help me with this!! I've been stuck on this for 2 days:(

Comment: It could be your security group does not allow ICMP traffic.

Answer (score 2):

> Please check below things

- Check the security group inbound rules
- Check NACL rules
- Check route tables rules (is IGW rules is present or not)